# Latin name of Good Friday

Tags: christianity, calendarium

Judging by [Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dies_Passionis_Domini) (I know, I know), Good Friday is known as *Dies Passionis Domini* in Latin.
This is a very direct name.
In English it is Good Friday, in Nordic countries Long Friday and [other names in other places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday#Name).
Latin is the only language I know which describes the day so directly.

Does Latin have a more indirect name for the day?
**In particular, is it called any kind of a Friday in Latin?**
Is *Dies Pessionis Domini* the only (common) one?
I know Latin does not have equally convenient names of weekdays as many other languages, so perhaps calling it a Friday would be awkward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This started out as a comment to comments made to Sam K's answer above but it ran away from itself a little so I'm posting it here!

Just to clarify, *parasceve* does refer to preparations for the Jewish Sabbath (and hence, Friday) but also to preparations for the Jewish Pesach/Passover, which can fall on any day of the week. Indeed, [New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11476a.htm) notes, “the Parasceve of the Pasch, whatever day of the week it fell on, was kept even more religiously than the ordinary Friday …”

The word was then adopted by Greek ecclesiastical writers although New Advent is not clear in what manner (was it to mean Friday? or some other day or period of preparation?)  It seems that *parasceve* as used in the Catholic church, refers [“chiefly”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parasceve) to Good Friday (see also [here](https://thelawdictionary.org/parasceve/), where *parasceve* is used for Good Friday and, moreover, in English law is a *dies non juridicus*).  And indeed, Good Friday of course *is* preparation for Pasch (Pesach); it just happens to always fall on Friday.

*[Feria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feria)* is used in Catholic liturgy for any day of the week except Sunday, each day being counted out from the Sabbath – *feria prima, feria secunda,* etc. Thus, *Feria sexta (VI)* simply means Friday.

*Feria VI in Parasceve* seems a curious redundancy then (*pace* the Roman Missal!) if *parasceve* alone is understood to mean Good Friday - it's like saying Friday on Good Friday!  Unless *parasceve* is actually considered to be the whole period of Holy Week. Unfortunately, I can’t find anywhere that *parasceve* *is* used in that way; it’s always specific to the Friday of Easter.

The *[Sacrosanctum Concilium](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19631204_sacrosanctum-concilium_lt.html)* uses *Feria VI in Passione et Morte Domini* (see point no. 110 - English [here](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19631204_sacrosanctum-concilium_en.html)) which I think better *describes* Good Friday but clearly *Feria VI in Parasceve* is the accepted use in Catholic Latin liturgy and has the added recommendation of referencing the Jewish origins of Pasch and Christianity itself.

Comment: Tomas Luis de Victoria wrote several motets to be used on Holy Thursday, Good Friday, and Holy Saturday, which were listed under the respective headings "Feria V in coena Domini ad Matutinum", "Feria VI in parasceve ad Matutinum", "Sabbato Sancto ad Matutinum": http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Tenebrae_Responsories_(Tom%C3%A1s_Luis_de_Victoria)

Answer (score 7):

You know, I wasn't expecting to find a wide variety of answers to this question in my search, but in just the [Morgan and Silva Furman University Lexicon](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/12/items/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon.pdf) there are a good number of answers. Let's take a look at them:

- *parasceve*, *-es* f. = a day of preparation, the day before the Sabbath (Note: the Sabbath is Saturday in the Jewish tradition)
- *dies parasceves* = the day of the day before the Sabbath (essentially the equivalent of the previous)
- *sexta feria parasceves* = the sixth holiday of the day before the Sabbath (this one makes less to me, but I believe it refers to the fact that Good Friday is the sixth day of Holy Week)
- *Feria Sexta in Parasceve* = the sixth holiday on the day before the Sabbath (similar to the previous)
- *Feria Sexta in Passione et Morte Domini* = the sixth holiday on the passion and death of the Lord
- *Passio Christi* = the passion of Christ

Now, the question becomes, which one do you use? I think if one looks at the original sources of these translations, then you can get a better idea as to the answer of this question. The very first answer comes from the 2nd-3rd century Christian writer Tertullian. This man wrote a great deal about the early Church, so this lends credibility that *parasceve* is perhaps the best option.

The second option comes from Ronald Latham, the third Christian Helfer, and the rest Edwin Levine. These are all more modern writers, but nearly all of them use that original *parasceve*.

Finally, a quick look online corroborates this. Two pages on the Catholic website New Advent ([here](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06643a.htm) and [here](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11476a.htm)) state that the day on which Jesus was crucified was called *parasceve* in the Bible, but in the Roman Missal it is called *Feria VI in Parasceve*. It therefore seems like one of these two options is your best bet for the Latin name of this holiday.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, would *parasceve* be declined like *Penelope*? I don't recall seeing non-names in the Greek first declension in Latin, so I'm not sure I got it right.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Wiktionary says that it is indeed a "first-declension, Greek type," so perhaps its just a unique exception. I am not as familiar with Greek declensions, so I do not know how definitive I can be on that topic.

Comment: I'm afraid all the names with parasceve on them refer to the preparations of the Jewish Pesach. I could be mistaken, though

Comment: I think Feria VI in Passione Domini is the most appropriate liturgical name. Side comment: The whole week is called hebdomada sancta. In Spanish good Friday is Viernes Santo, as are all days of holy week (lunes santo, sábado santo). That is not the case in Latin, I'm afraid

Comment: @Rafael It is true that it can reference the Jewish Sabbath. That was its original meaning. But, like many Christian, religious terms, it was appropriated beyond its original meaning. And again, the Roman Missal calls it _Feria VI in Parasceve_ according to New Advent. A Google search for both terms turns up results for both. I think the "Passion of the Lord" part of what you suggest refers more to the whole of Holy Week, while what I found, although redundant, refers more specifically to Friday. In summary, I think either would work seeing as they both came up in my original search.

Comment: But those are just my two cents. :)

Comment: feria sexta simply means "Friday", the sixth day of the week (counting from Sunday).

Comment: @Rafael Are you sure it's *hebdomada* in nominative? I thought it's *hebdomas*, gen. *hebdomadis*. Perhaps *hebdomada* is a Latinization into the first declension?

Comment: @fdb Can _feria sexta_ really mean any old Friday? I thought _feria_ had more of a "holiday" connotation.

Comment: The Roman missal is an important source for both good Friday and hebdomada

Comment: @SamK. Common in Christian authors: http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/FERIAE1. And also in inscriptions.

Comment: I would probably translate "sexta feria parascaves" as "the sixth weekday, [the weekday] of the Passover"; similarly, "feria sexta in Parasceve" might be "the sixth weekday, on the Passover". I've most often seen it in the ablative, where it would be well translated "on the sixth weekday, on Passover".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta in my breviary it's always first declension *hebdomada* in the rubrics, but sometimes third declension *hebdomas* in the text.

Answer (score 5):

Christianity traditionally marks out from the calendar the week (Sunday to Saturday) before Easter Sunday. We call it Holy Week, *hebdomada sancta*. The Sunday before Easter Sunday and the three days immediately preceding it are particularly important : Palm Sunday, on which the entry of Jesus Christ into Jerusalem is celebrated; Holy, or Maundy, Thursday, on which his Last Supper is celebrated; Good Friday, on which his death is remembered; and Holy Saturday, in which we wait expectantly for his resurrection. These last three days are called (in both Latin and English) the Triduum.

"Maxima Redemptionis", a general decree of the [Sacred Congregation of Rites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_Congregation_of_Rites) issued in 1955, discusses the observations of Holy Week, and in the process gives (presumably typical) names for them. It states in its discussion of the Divine Office (the daily prayers said by religious and many lay Catholics):

> Dominica II Passionis seu in palmis, feria II, III, et IV hebdomadae sanctae, officium divinum horis consuetis persolvitur.
>
> In triduo sacro, id est: feria V in Cena Domini, feria VI in Passione et Morte Domini<sup>*</sup>, et sabbato sancto, si officium peragatur *in choro*, vel *in communi*, haec serventur.
>
> ["Maxima Redemptionis"](http://vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_19551116_maximaredemptionis_la.html)

That is:

> On the Second Sunday of the Passion, or in the Palms, [and on] the second, third, and fourth [weekday] of Holy Week, the Divine Office is to be performed at the usual hours.
>
> During the Sacred Triduum, that is: on the fifth weekday [Thursday], at the Supper of the Lord; on the sixth weekday [Friday], at the Passion and Death of the Lord; and on Holy Saturday, if the Office may be performed in choir, or in common, let them [i.e. the group reciting the Hours] observe it.

I conclude, then, that the "Feria N" is an ablative of time referring to the day *purely as a weekday name*, and the "in cena...", "in passione...", "in parasceve" are appositive phrases describing the feast observed on that day.

It seems that the names of the days of the Triduum are therefore

- **Feria V, in cena domini** [*Thursday, on the Supper of the Lord*]
- **Feria VI, in passione et morte Domini** (or in parasceve) [*Friday, on the passion and death of the Lord*; or *Friday, on the Passover*]
- **Sabbatum sanctum** [*Holy Saturday*]

---

<sup>*</sup>The phrase "feria VI in parasceve" does not occur in this document; however, it does in, for example, the encyclicals ["Redemptoris Nostri Cruciatus"](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-enc_19490415_redemptoris-nostri-cruciatus.html) of Pope Pius XII and ["Fides et Ratio"](http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_14091998_fides-et-ratio.html) of Pope John Paul II.

Answer (score 3):

Here I answer my pending comments, and give an answer from the POV of current Catholic liturgy:

Good Friday is **Feria Sexta in Passione Domini**. This is the title given for the corresponding day in the [Roman Missal](https://media.musicasacra.com/books/latin_missal2002.pdf) (p. 313,) as well as the name used to refer to the day in every cross reference on it. Penelope is right if you consider older versions of the Missal, or look from the outside of Catholic liturgy. I was wrong in thinking parasceve was an exclusively Jewish term, however:

1. The word *parasceve* does not occur a single time in the 2002 Missal (this excludes readings.)

   - In the 1962 one (last *tridentine* version,) it is interchangeable with Passione Domini, and is used exclusively for Good Friday.
   - In the Clementine Vulgate, *parasceve* occurs 6 times ([according to this](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch).) and every time it refers to the day of the passion of the Lord in the sense it was the day of preparation of the Jewish passover.
2. The word **feria** as in feria secunda to feria sexta is common church Latin for weekdays (obviously names honouring pagan gods aren't quite appropriate.) Only Saturday (*[sabbatum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsabbatum)*, from Hebrew) and Sunday (*dominica* from... er... you guessed, *Dominus*) have *special* names.

   - If *feria prima* was ever used to refer to Sunday, I can't find a single use in the Missal.
   - Specific Sundays (like the day of the Resurrection) in the Gospels are called *prima sabbati*, the first day after Saturday, possibly omitting *feria*. Its morning is also called *mane prima sabbati* where *mane* could be acting either [as a noun or as an adverb](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmane). This sounds like a precedent of *feria prima* that was quickly replaced by *dies Domini(ca)* and did't survive in liturgy.

   So, answering that part of the question, **calling Good Friday a Friday** (feria VI) **is not awkward at all**.
3. Hebdomada as n. for week, is accepted as per [L&S](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch). It is equivalent to *hebdomas*.